# Will Apache + Thin + SSE work?

Tags: apache, sinatra, thin, server-sent-events

We use Apache as a proxy in front of all of our applications. Will using Apache in front of Thin as a proxy server work? I am hoping to do a chat type of application like the one delivered with Sinatra.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've had success doing this with the below Apache config settings.

```
ProxyPass /stream_event http://127.0.0.1:9292
ProxyPassReverse /stream_event http://127.0.0.1:9292
```

See this post for more details. [Server Sent Event connection not staying open with Apache/Thin/Sinatra](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14664362/server-sent-event-connection-not-staying-open-with-apache-thin-sinatra/14674819#14674819)